# Check if string does not have 6 digit number

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to check if a string does not have any 6 digit number.

```
$myString = "https://www.website.net/sometext/123456/";

if ( preg_match( '/([^0-9]{6})/', $myString ) ) {
    echo 'If'; 
} else {
    echo 'Else';
}
```

The code above echos `if` which it should be false. I am not sure what I am missing.

This what I'm trying to achieve:

```
"https://www.website.net/sometext/123456/" -> false
"https://www.website.net/sometext/"        -> true
"https://www.website.net/"                 -> true
```

Comment: Just make the regex check that it does and swap the conditions. You can do it with regex alone (negative lookahead), but it's less readable.

Comment: try this regex:   /([0-9]{6})/

Comment: To check for six digits present anywhere, just use `preg_match('/([0-9]{6})/', $myString)`

Comment: A `1234567` is not a six digit number, why do you want to fail it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either check whether the result of the `preg_match` is 0, while using `\d{6}`:

```
if ( preg_match( '/\d{6}/', $myString ) === 0) {
    echo 'If'; 
} else {
    echo 'Else';
}
```

Or, if you wanted the `preg_match` to return `1` if the string doesn't contain any such number, repeat each character from the start to the end of the string while using negative lookahead for 6 characters:

```
if ( preg_match( '/^(?:.(?!\d{6}))+$/', $myString )) {
    echo 'If'; 
} else {
    echo 'Else';
}
```

Also note that `[^0-9]` means "anything but a digit" - but, that can be matched just with the `\D` metacharacter instead. (similarly, to match a digit, or `[0-9]`, use `\d` - don't use the character sets)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to say "not this" in regex, express that in PHP:

```
if ( preg_match( '/([0-9]{6})/', $myString ) !== 1) {
    echo 'If'; 
} else {
    echo 'Else';
}
```

Your current regex `/([^0-9]{6})/` means "6 non-digit characters", not "does not contain 6 digits".

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match('/[0-9]\d{5}/',$myString)) {
    echo 'If';
}else{
    echo 'else';
}
```

Comment: I might be missing something, but what's the difference between `'/[0-9]\d{5}/` and `'/[0-9]{6}/` ?

Comment: You aren't missing anything and \d is compact form of [0-9]

Comment: `\d` is not the same thing since it matches ALL Unicode digits, including ones from other scripts such as `९`.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression matches any string with 6 consecutive non-digit chars. You need to match string with 6 digits then inverse the result:

```
if ( ! preg_match('/([0-9]{6})/', $myString)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may match a 6 digit number with `(?<!\d)\d{6}(?!\d)` pattern.

You may use it in a `preg_match` call and negate the result:

```
if (!preg_match('~(?<!\d)\d{6}(?!\d)~', "text1234567 more text")) { 
    echo "Does not contain a 6 digit number"; 
}
```

Or, you may add it to the negative lookahead and use `preg_match` without negation:

```
if (preg_match('~^(?!.*(?<!\d)\d{6}(?!\d))~s', "text1234567 more text")) { 
    echo "Does not contain a 6 digit number"; 
}
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/6g5wg4).

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*(?<!\d)\d{6}(?!\d))` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a match of

  - `.*` - any 0+ chars as many as possible (`s` modifier makes `.` match any char)
  - `(?<!\d)\d{6}(?!\d)` - 6 digits that are neither preceded nor followed with a digit.